# Classifying space of Sporadic groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology, finite-groups, classifying-spaces

Which are the classifying spaces of the $26$ Sporadic groups? Is there something special in those classifying spaces $BG$ more than the fact that $\pi_1(BG)=G$?

Comment: It's unclear what would constitute an answer to this question.

Comment: Sorry. I suppose that the problem is the second part: I'm trying to ask if the classifying spaces of the sporadic groups have unique characteristics such that aren't possible to find in other spaces more than them just because they're the $BG$ of sporadic groups.

Comment: The book "Classifying spaces of sporadic groups" by Benson and Smith may help you. Chapter 6 contains a bit of history about the geometry of finite simple groups of Lie type and analogues for sporadic groups. The prime 2 plays a special role for these groups, hence the study of 2-local geometries, but hopefully an expert on finite groups can expand on this.